# Fibonacci calculator steps

Tags: javascript

Everything work but I have a question on this Fibonacci calculator (see in-code comment). Could I skip the console.debug step? Why is it needed?

```
var getFibSum = document.getElementById("sumFib");


getFibSum.onclick = function(){
               document.getElementById("sumFibResult").innerHTML = fiftyEvenFibonacciSum();
 }


 function fiftyEvenFibonacciSum(){
 /// WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
 var first,second,add;
    for(var i=0;i<50;i++){
        if(i === 0){
            first = 1;
            second = 2;
        }
        /** Why do I have  to do the following to make it work?:*/
        if(first+second > Number.MAX_VALUE){
            console.debug(i, first, second);
            return;
        }
        add = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = add;
    }

    return(add);
}
```

Or would this other way be the most efficient way to write the Fibonacci function to calculate the sum of first 50 numbers:

```
var getFibSum = document.getElementById("sumFib");


getFibSum.onclick = function(){
               document.getElementById("sumFibResult").innerHTML = fiftyEvenFibonacciSum();
 }


 function fiftyEvenFibonacciSum(){
 /// WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
 var first,second,add;
    for(var i=0;i<50;i++){
        if(i === 0){
            first = 1;
            second = 2;

        add = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = add;
    }

    return(add);
}
```

Comment: Because if `first + second` is more than `Number.MAX_VALUE` it cannot calculate it, and hence just returns nothing (`return;`). You can remove the `console.debug` part, though.

Comment: Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/G8cST/) for the sum of first 50 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number.MAX_VALUE is the maximum value your system can address and that part of code actually stops the script and outputs the last numbers in case you go over that max value.

Since you're doing only 50 iterations, it's highly unlikely you'll even come close to that number, so you can freely remove the whole if-clause if it bothers you.

Comment: How can first + second be bigger than that, if it's the max value that can be addressed ?

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux `Infinity > Number.MAX_VALUE` gives `true`

Comment: No need to unaccept my answer because you added another question to this one... Aside from being rude, you need to ask another question, not update the existing closed ones.

Comment: I'm very sorry Shomz, I'm new here and i'm just trying to find my way around. I didn't mean to be rude, but was looking for further explanations to my ongoing problem.

Comment: No problem, but keep it one question per question. :) If everybody would ask a few questions on the same page, this would turn into a forum and not knowledge base.

Comment: You function is ok. If you wish to make it more optimized and practice your own coding skills, try to write it as a recursive function. I'm sure you'll find nice answers here on SO.

Comment: I didn't know that the way to go further is to ask a different question. I'll will do it from now on. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Yeah, because as soon as you accept an answer, the question is marked as closed... Why don't you check out the tour of SO: http://stackoverflow.com/tour You'll see that SO encourages research and helping in very specific problems, and not giving complete codes, etc. See what kind of questions you should and shouldn't post here. And welcome aboard! :)

Answer (score 0):

console.debug just prints some debug information, it can be removed safely.